# Receiving UDP broadcast [VirtualBox, Ubuntu, Python]

Tags: python, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, broadcast

I have a Ubuntu virtual machine listening for UDP broadcast packets which are generated by the host machine. If I bind to either of my network interfaces eth1 or lo (local loopback) using python's socket.bind method I don't receive any packets. If, however, I bind using '' (the symbol for all interfaces) then everything is fine. I would expect that it was possible to bind to just the address of eth1, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Could someone explain why the '' is required? Is there something funky going on because I am using a virtual machine? I'm using a bridged-network setup so the virtual machine looks like another machine on my LAN. Here's the code:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1) 

# using the '' address works
sock.bind(('', UDP_PORT))
# using the address of eth1 doesn't
#sock.bind(('192.168.2.123', UDP_PORT))
# and neither does using the local loopback
#sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recv(2048)
    print data
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 doesn't work either. For some reason it has to be the '' address which is what I don't understand. I'll change my code to be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In network programming empty address string denotes *all configured interfaces*. If however IP address is specified, socket will only listen on interface with specified IP address.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option '<broadcast>' to bind to a broadcast address (according to http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html). So I'd suggest that  you try to use your interface's broadcast address, like 192.168.2.255 (assuming your network is 192.168.2.0/24).